# Compiling php 5.2 from source under 12.04, apxs2 (via libtools) ignores the -prefix used with ./configure

Tags: apache2, compiling, php

In the source directory:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/ashkan/Development/php/bin/php-5.2  --with-mysql --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2
```

`make` works fine but `make install` says:

```
Installing PHP SAPI module:       apache2handler
/usr/share/apache2/build/instdso.sh SH_LIBTOOL='/usr/share/apr-1.0/build/libtool' libphp5.la /usr/lib/apache2/modules
/usr/share/apr-1.0/build/libtool --mode=install cp libphp5.la /usr/lib/apache2/modules/
libtool: install: cp .libs/libphp5.so /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so': Permission denied
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

UPDATE: reading `man apxs2` it seems apxs compiles and then installs the module into `apache module directory`. This module directory seems to be fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this blog article](https://blog.thecybershadow.net/2013/01/25/installing-php-and-apache-module-under-home/), if you specify `INSTALL_ROOT` the PHP apache module will try to install in that directory.

```
INSTALL_ROOT=/the/dir/path/to/install/in make install
```

The other thing you might want to try adding this option to your `./configure` of php-src:

```
--libexecdir=DIR        program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]
--sysconfdir=DIR        read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]
```

as I believe those are being used in the Makefile

Answer (score 0):

No permission to copy binaries to `/usr`. Do `sudo make install`.

Comment: Tnx for your reply but as mentioned in the question, the problem is that `--prefix` is used with `./configure` and the `libtools` is supposed to copy the module in the proper location and not the `/usr/lib/apache2/module`

Comment: Try putting --prefix in "" --prefix="/home/ashkan/Development/php/bin/php-5.2"

Comment: You could try tooling with the config file. I looked briefly. its not fixed "phplibdir" is it's assignment. you could try adding set -vx into the configure script to see what it is doing with your prefix directive.